# How to Store QR code values in Custom object Field

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am able to generate QR code for some object fields and values are displayed as per procedure while scanning QR code using mobile App.But i need to fetch values from QR code by scanning and need to store in any object Fields. Is there any ways to implement this? Please suggest me some ideas to proceed with either Lightning component or any other.

Answer (score 0):

Store the QR image encoded as a Base64 string in a DB Field. Convert the Base64 to PNG/JPG as needed.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: While this is an answer, I think it misunderstands the question. Regardless, it does not provide enough detail to be very useful.